# Primer registro top

Tags: sql-server

HOLA BUEN DIA TENGO LA SIGUIENTE CONSULTA:

```
SELECT --TOP 1
    TRANSPORTISTAS.GUIA AS GUIA
    ,FORMAT(TRANSPORTISTAS.FECHA,'d','eu') AS FECHA
    ,TRANSPORTISTAS.HORA AS HORA
    ,(CASE WHEN TRANSPORTISTAS.TIP_OPE='001' THEN 'RECOLECCION' WHEN TRANSPORTISTAS.TIP_OPE='002' THEN 'ENTREGA' WHEN TRANSPORTISTAS.TIP_OPE='003' THEN 'RECIBIDO' END) AS TIP_OPE

FROM TRANSPORTISTAS AS TRANSPORTISTAS
ORDER BY TRANSPORTISTAS.C2 DESC, TRANSPORTISTAS.C3 DESC

GUIA    FECHA           HORA    TIP_OPE
5340    25/02/2019  17:45:20    RECIBIDO
5340    25/02/2019  17:45:15    ENTREGA
5340    25/02/2019  17:45:01    RECOLECCION

5641    25/02/2019  16:28:12    RECIBIDO
5641    25/02/2019  16:27:54    ENTREGA
5641    25/02/2019  16:27:36    RECOLECCION

5642    25/02/2019  16:28:12    ENTREGA
5642    25/02/2019  16:27:54    ENTREGA
5642    25/02/2019  16:27:36    RECOLECCION
```

LO QUE QUIERO HACER ES QUE TRAER EL PRIMER REGISTRO SIEMPRE Y CUANDO EL TIP_OPE ES "RECIBIDO"

QUEDADO ASI EL RESULTADO:

```
GUIA    FECHA           HORA    TIP_OPE
5340    25/02/2019  17:45:20    RECIBIDO
5641    25/02/2019  16:28:12    RECIBIDO
```

NADA MAS QUIERO LOS PRIMEROS SIEMPRE Y CUANDO SEA RECIBIDO Y LOS QUE NO SON SE OMITEN HABIA PENSADO CON UN TOP PERO NOSE COMO PLASMARLO

Comment: no es where tip_obe = "recibido"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas verificar que la primer fila sea RECIBIDO, necesitas algo para identificarla.

```
WITH cteTransportistas AS(
    SELECT --TOP 1
        T.GUIA AS GUIA
        ,FORMAT(T.FECHA,'d','eu') AS FECHA
        ,T.HORA AS HORA
        ,T.TIP_OPE AS TIP_OPE
        ,CASE WHEN T.TIP_OPE='001' THEN 'RECOLECCION' 
                WHEN T.TIP_OPE='002' THEN 'ENTREGA' 
                WHEN T.TIP_OPE='003' THEN 'RECIBIDO' END AS TIP_OPE_DESC
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY T.GUIA ORDER BY T.FECHA DESC, T.HORA DESC) AS RN
    FROM TRANSPORTISTAS AS T
)
SELECT GUIA,
    FECHA,
    HORA,
    TIP_OPE_DESC
FROM cteTransportistas
WHERE TIP_OPE = '003'
AND RN = 1
ORDER BY FECHA DESC, HORA DESC;
```

Comment: SI ME SIRVIO ASI ERA AMIGO MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!

Comment: Espero que entiendas que se utiliza el código del tipo de operación en vez de su descripción para poder aprovechar un índice en caso de existir.

Answer (score 0):

Solo deberías agregar una condición de filtro a tu consulta.

```
SELECT
     TRANSPORTISTAS.GUIA AS GUIA
    ,FORMAT(TRANSPORTISTAS.FECHA,'d','eu') AS FECHA
    ,TRANSPORTISTAS.HORA AS HORA
    ,(CASE 
        WHEN TRANSPORTISTAS.TIP_OPE='001' THEN 'RECOLECCION' 
        WHEN TRANSPORTISTAS.TIP_OPE='002' THEN 'ENTREGA' 
        WHEN TRANSPORTISTAS.TIP_OPE='003' THEN 'RECIBIDO' 
      END) AS TIP_OPE
FROM TRANSPORTISTAS AS TRANSPORTISTAS
WHERE TRANSPORTISTAS.TIP_OPE='003'
ORDER BY 
    TRANSPORTISTAS.C2 DESC, 
    TRANSPORTISTAS.C3 DESC
```